# Understanding uber startup screen reporter code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am React Native engineer trying to understand/learn objective c.

I was going through [Uber Startup screen](https://github.com/uber/startup-reason-reporter) reporter code, and have some difficulties [understanding the code](https://github.com/uber/startup-reason-reporter#use)

Here is the code sample they have shared

Can someone explain me the flow of code?

What I have been doing (not sure if it is correct).

In AppDelegate.h, Added notification relay

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterNotificationRelay *notificationRelay;
```

In AppDelegate.mm

I have added these delegate they shared..

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.notificationRelay updateApplicationStateNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil]];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.notificationRelay updateApplicationStateNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil]];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.notificationRelay updateApplicationStateNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil]];
}
```

then I created a new Cocoa Touch class and add this code there (inside shared instance), something like this.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
      
      // Determine whether the app crashed on a prior launch
      BOOL crashedOnPriorLaunch = false;

      // Initialize a storage mechanism implementing UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfoProtocol
      id<UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfoProtocol> runInfo = ...

      // Initialize the notification relay
      id<UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterNotificationRelayProtocol> = [[UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterNotificationRelay alloc] init]

      // Initialize the startup reason reporter
      UBApplicationStartupReasonReporter *startupReasonReporter = [[UBApplicationStartupReasonReporter alloc] initWithPreviousRunDidCrash:crashedOnPriorLaunch
              previousRunInfo:runInfo
              notificationRelay: notificationRelay
              debugging:[UBBuildType isDebugBuild]];

      // Profit
      UBStartupReason startupReason = startupReasonReporter.startupReason;

 
    }
    return self;
}
```

**[Question:]**
I am not sure how is the value of `UBStartupReason startupReason = startupReasonReporter.startupReason;`  going to update? For example we have `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillResignActive` which are two separate event.

Comment: The point is you are supposed to do something with the `startupReason` variable once it has a value. In your case you don't do anything with it.  The value it has was set during the startup process or as a result of one of the notifications being posted in the app delegate methods. . You need to structure your code so that you re run the "profit" code when you need to know the most recent startup reason

Answer (score 1):

If you see the code in github link that is provided, the `startupReasonReporter.startupReason` is updated based on the `previousRunInfo` data whenever `startupReasonReporter` is instantiated with `initWithPreviousRunDidCrash` with the `previousRunInfo` (or `runInfo` in your case) when the app is run the next time.

You have to use below public method to get the `runInfo` instance which is

```
/**
 *  Returns the prior run information stored to disk at the given directory URL.
 *  @param directoryURL The directory to use to to store the startup reason data.
 *  @return the previous startup reason data if it was present on disk, or empty startup reason object.
 */
+ (nonnull instancetype)priorRunAtDirectoryURL:(nullable NSURL *)directoryURL;
```

The way you are initializing `runInfo` seems to be incorrect.
You have to do something like below:

```
id<UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfoProtocol> runInfo = [[UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfo] alloc] priorRunAtDirectoryURL:<yourDirectoryURL>];
```

These delegates `applicationDidBecomeActive`, `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationWillTerminate` whenever called will just update the `runInfo` for the current run which will be store in a file in directory that you have provided in `<yourDirectoryURL>` in above call and the data will be retrieved from this file into `startupReasonReporter.startupReason` when the app is run next time.

Every time when you run the app the previous run data will be retrieved and `startupReasonReporter.startupReason` is set based on the data available in `previousRunInfo`

Comment: If this clarifies your question. Please accept the answer